# Check for a lot of settings.ini options?

Tags: python-3.x, settings

Given a settings.ini file with tons of settings, I am checking each setting if it exists with:

```
CONFIG = configparser.ConfigParser()
CONFIG.read("settings.ini")

if CONFIG.has_option("A", "A_Config"):
    A_conf = CONFIG.get("A", "A_Config")
else:
    A_conf = "wrong_A_conf"

if CONFIG.has_option("B", "B_Config"):
    B_conf = CONFIG.get("B", "B_Config")
else:
    B_conf = "wrong_B_conf"
```

Is there another way to check 10, 20, 50 settings options?
Should I need to write this validity check for each setting option?

Please advise.

Comment: So you want to check if all keys inside sections have values?

Comment: Yes and if not give them a default value. @andreis11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding your issue, I want to suggest these approaches:

Taking in consideration `sample.ini`'s content:

```
[A]
A_config = 1
[B]
B_config = 2
[C]
C_config = 
[D]
D_config =
```

- *Approach 1*

  ```
  import configparser
  config = configparser.ConfigParser()
  config.read('sample.ini')

  default_value = 999

  for each_section in config.sections():
      for key, value in config[each_section].items():
          if value == "":
              globals()[f"{each_section}_config"] = default_value
          else:
              globals()[f"{each_section}_config"] = value    
  print(A_config)
  print(B_config)
  print(C_config)
  print(D_config)
  ```

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach.

(Pylint shows the `Undefined variable 'foo7_config'`but the code works)

The reason I wouldn't take on this approach is because you can accidentally override something in the namespace.

- *'Safer' approach (number 2)*

Assign all variables (`A_config, B_config ...`) first, with a default value.

I know it's a tedious job, but you will do it once and update the list on the go.

```
A_config, B_config, ..., N_config = [0 for x in range(N)] # or store them in a list.
```

- ***Approach 3 (my recommendation)***

Store them in a dict, without needing to manually declare them.

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('sample.ini')

default_value = 999

new_dict = dict()

for each_section in config.sections():
    for key, value in config[each_section].items():
        if value == "":
            new_dict[f"{each_section}_config"] = default_value
        else:
            new_dict[f"{each_section}_config"] = value

print(new_dict)
# 1
print(new_dict['A_config'])

# 2
print(new_dict['B_config'])

# empty
print(new_dict['C_config'])

# empty
print(new_dict['D_config'])
```

*Note*: if you encounter this situation:

```
[N]
N_config
```

You can catch them (try/except) the case by catching the `configparser.ParsingError`. This error is triggered by the lack of delimiter.

Used the codes in [this online compiler](https://repl.it/repls/HoarsePurpleAddin).